# Groupby and LINQ node js

Tags: javascript, linq, node.js

I use node-linq and I try to understand the GroupBy, but the documentation is so little

for example I have this data :

> {"date":"2013/06/26","name":"A","number":1}
>
> {"date":"2013/06/26","name":"A","number":5}
>
> {"date":"2013/06/27","name":"B","number":4}
>
> {"date":"2013/06/27","name":"A","number":4}

and I want write like this query but with LINQ for node js

```
SELECT date, name, SUM(number)
FROM data
GROUPBY date, name
```

I try this code but I get Errors

```
var o = new LINQ(data)
        .Select(function(name,d) {return name.statement,d.date;})
        .SUM((function(x) {return x.number;)
        .GroupBy(function(name,d) {return name.statement,d.date;}
    .ToArray()
```

has somebody any suggestions or just some examples about GroupBy ? Thanks

Comment: Don't even think of LINQ as SQL; it really doesn't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While you can see that there's `.GroupBy` in the README on github, there is no `.GroupBy` when you do `npm install node-linq`. So you'll have to install the module with

```
npm install https://github.com/wearefractal/node-linq/tarball/master
```

This is your data:

```
var LINQ = require('node-linq').LINQ;

var data = [ { date: '2013/06/26', name: 'A', number: 1 },
             { date: '2013/06/26', name: 'A', number: 5 },
             { date: '2013/06/27', name: 'B', number: 4 },
             { date: '2013/06/27', name: 'A', number: 4 } ];
```

First, you want to group them. Unfortunately, you can't group by a hash so you'll have to use a surrogate key:

```
var o = new LINQ(data).GroupBy(function(row) { return row.date + '~' + row.name; });
console.log(o);
```

This is the output:

```
{ '2013/06/26~A':
   [ { date: '2013/06/26', name: 'A', number: 1 },
     { date: '2013/06/26', name: 'A', number: 5 } ],
  '2013/06/27~B': [ { date: '2013/06/27', name: 'B', number: 4 } ],
  '2013/06/27~A': [ { date: '2013/06/27', name: 'A', number: 4 } ] }
```

Next, you want to sum the numbers, but you can't.

```
console.log(o.__proto__); // {}
```

Perhaps you can need to wrap it in `LINQ`?

```
new LINQ(o); // InvalidCastException: Data not Array
```

Nope.

Let's convert the object to an array by losing the keys. There's no `Object.values()` in JavaScript, so we have to do it this way:

```
o = new LINQ(Object.keys(o).map(function(key) { return o[key] }));
```

Now we can finally sum all numbers:

```
o = o.Select(function(rows) { return { date: rows[0].date, name: rows[0].name, sum: new LINQ(rows).Sum(function(row) { return row.number; }) } }).ToArray();
console.log(o);
```

This is the result:

```
[ { date: '2013/06/26', name: 'A', sum: 6 },
  { date: '2013/06/27', name: 'B', sum: 4 },
  { date: '2013/06/27', name: 'A', sum: 4 } ]
```

Not very pretty.

### Underscore

`npm install underscore`

Here's how to group your data using the `underscore` library.

```
var _ = require('underscore')._;

var data = [ { date: '2013/06/26', name: 'A', number: 1 },
             { date: '2013/06/26', name: 'A', number: 5 },
             { date: '2013/06/27', name: 'B', number: 4 },
             { date: '2013/06/27', name: 'A', number: 4 } ];

var grouper = function(row) { return row.date + '~' + row.name; };
var summer = function(rows) { return rows.reduce(function(sum, row) { return sum + row.number; }, 0); };

var o  = _.chain(data)
          .groupBy(grouper)
          .map(function(rows) { return { date: rows[0].date, name: rows[0].name, sum: summer(rows) }; })
          .value();

console.log(o); // same result
```

Much nicer, I think.

Comment: I understand thank you very much for your help, the code works 100%

Answer (score 3):

There are some errors in your code there:

- The callback functions accept only one argument, not two
- In Node (and Javascript) if you want to return multiple items, put them in an object or an array (wrap with {} for example)
- Your braces and parenthesis aren't matching in a few cases.

For example, instead of:

```
.Select(function(name,d) {return name.statement,d.date;})
```

you should write:

```
.Select(function(item) { return { name: item.name, date: item.date } } )
```

and instead of:

```
.GroupBy(function(name,d) {return name.statement,d.date;}
```

you should write:

```
.GroupBy(function(item) { return { name: item.name, date: item.date } } )
```

However, GroupBy is unimplemented for asynchronous link as mentioned in the notes at the top of the ALINQ.coffee (# TODO: GroupBy, ContainsAll)

And ECMAScript prior to 6 does not have big arrow => style lambda notation, so you'd have to use some combinations of map and reduce in order to achieve the same functionality as far as I am aware, which would probably mean enhancing the node-linq library with that capability.

The closest you can get using node-linq right now is probably something like this:

```
var statement = [{"date":"2013/06/26","name":"A","number":1},
{"date":"2013/06/26","name":"A","number":5},
{"date":"2013/06/27","name":"B","number":4},
{"date":"2013/06/27","name":"A","number":4}]

var o = new LINQ(statement)
        .Select(function(item) {
               return {
                   date: item.date,
                   name: item.name, 
                   sum: new LINQ(statement).Sum(function(item){return item.number;})
               };
        })
        .OrderBy(function(item) {
               return [item.name, item.date];
         })
        .ToArray();

console.log(o);
```

which gives:

```
[ { date: '2013/06/26', name: 'A', sum: 14 },
  { date: '2013/06/26', name: 'A', sum: 14 },
  { date: '2013/06/27', name: 'A', sum: 14 },
  { date: '2013/06/27', name: 'B', sum: 14 } ]
```

In order to fix the sum part, use map and reduce.  For example, you could look into lambda-js: https://github.com/dfellis/lambda-js